# Proving Inequality with Square Roots and Algebraic Manipulation

Tags: inequality

**Question:**

Edit: Original question is: Estimate $\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\cdots+\sqrt{10000}$ to nearest hundred.

I used $\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\cdots+\sqrt{n}\geq \int_{0}^{n}\sqrt{x}dx$ and $\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\cdots+\sqrt{n}\leq \frac{4n+3}{6}\sqrt{n}$, which I need to prove.

So prove that: $$\left ( \frac{4n+3}{6} \right )\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}\leq \left ( \frac{4n+7}{6} \right )\sqrt{n+1}$$

**Attempt:**
$$\left ( \frac{4n+3}{6} \right )\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}= \frac{(4n+3)\sqrt{n}+6\sqrt{n+1}}{6}\leq \frac{(4n+3)\sqrt{n+1}+6\sqrt{n+1}}{6}= \frac{(4n+9)\sqrt{n+1}}{6}$$

But $$\frac{(4n+9)\sqrt{n+1}}{6}\geq \frac{(4n+7)\sqrt{n+1}}{6}$$

How can I prove that $$\frac{(4n+3)\sqrt{n}+6\sqrt{n+1}}{6}\leq \frac{(4n+7)\sqrt{n+1}}{6}$$

Comment: You'll need to take less of a leap on that inequality in line 1. Can you think of something else to do?

Comment: Are you really *asked* to use induction?

Comment: Yes, it asks for a prove by induction before I can use the inequality to estimate the sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desired inequality

$$\frac{(4n+3)\sqrt{n}+6\sqrt{n+1}}{6}\leq \frac{(4n+7)\sqrt{n+1}}{6}$$

is equivalent to

$$(4n+3)\sqrt{n}\le(4n+1)\sqrt{n+1}\;.$$

Since we’re dealing with non-negative numbers here, this is equivalent to

$$n(16n^2+24n+9)\le(n+1)(16n^2+8n+1)\;.$$

If you expand that, you’ll see that it’s true.

Comment: Thank you very much! I noticed that when ever doing induction involving inequalities, it is best to remove any unnecessary terms. Simplifying the expression and leaving only what is necessary to prove makes it much easier.

Comment: @user2357: This is why I asked do you really need to do induction. It is a straightforward non-induction manipulation.

Comment: @user2357: You’re very welcome.

Comment: @André: But this is the induction step of the OP’s argument.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: $\left ( \frac{4n+3}{6} \right )\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}\leq \left ( \frac{4n+7}{6} \right )\sqrt{n+1}$  was the third step of induction because the original question involves a series. Is there another way without using induction?

Comment: Sure, but one solution is enough. The error in the approximation is mostly due to the first few terms. So by calculating the first few terms "exactly" we can be more relaxed about error estimates for the rest.